# Keep rows with more than True condition

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    A     B      C        D      
0   1   True    False   True
1   3   False   False   False
2   4   True    True    True
...
```

How do I create a filter to only keep rows with more than 1 True condition?

There are additional columns that I've not included here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `sum` each row's boolean values, and filter for sums greater than 1:

```
df = df[df[['B', 'C', 'D']].sum(axis=1) > 1]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    A     B      C     D
0  1  True  False  True
2  4  True   True  True
```

If you want to just select all the boolean columns, use `select_dtypes`:

```
df = df[df.select_dtypes('bool').sum(axis=1) > 1]
```